# Translation request - one sentence from German - from a paper by Hilbert.

Tags: geometry, translation-request

I am trying to translate a paper by Hilbert written in German. 
I am mostly done, but I am stuck on another sentence. If anyone
could give me a rough translation of the following proposition it would
be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

alle Wege zwischen den beiden Punkten A und B von
derselben Eigenschaft sich aus den construirten Wegen zusammensetzen
lassen und dass die übrigen Verbindungswege von grösserer Gesammtlänge
sind.

This is what I have so far, using Google and Bing translate and context:

All paths between the two points A and B,
composed of the constructed paths, have the same property, 
and that the remaining connecting paths are of greater total length.

[EDIT: the full sentence, at page 88 from this [link]](https://archive.org/download/grunddergeovon00hilbrich/grunddergeovon00hilbrich.pdf)

> In dem betrachteten Falle ist also zwischen gewissen Punkten A und B
>   ein aus zwei geradlinigen Stücken zusammengesetzter Weg möglich,
>   dessen Gesamtlänge gleich der direkten Entfernung der beiden Punkte A
>   und B ist; es läßt sich ohne Schwierigkeit zeigen, daß *alle Wege
>   zwischen den beiden Punkten A und B von derselben Eigenschaft sich aus
>   den konstruierten Wegen zusammensetzen lassen und daß die übrigen
>   Verbindungsivege von größerer Gesamtlänge sind*.

Comment: This does not appear to be the entire sentence; could you give us the whole thing?

Comment: the quote sounds more like something Yoda would say

Comment: @Chris I have added the whole sentence and a link to the text (pdf) for those who want more context

Comment: Found it: Thus, in the case under consideration there can be between certain points $A$ and $B$ a path comprising two straight pieces whose combined length is equal to the direct distance between the points $A$ and $B$; it can be shown without difficulty that all paths between the points $A$ and $B$ with the same property can be assembled from the constructed paths, and that the remaining connecting paths have greater total length.

Answer (score 1):

> [that] all paths between the two points A and B of the same property
>   can be composed of the constructed paths and that other connecting
>   paths have a larger overall length.

The first part of the sentence is missing, but this should be it.

Comment: You're welcome. Who voted me down? Could you at least leave a comment, please?

Comment: @Brian M. Scott Do you know if that paper by Hilbert has been translated into English? I've translated the whole paper up to the paragraph you've pasted. My translation of the initial part of the paragraph, the one you've pasted agrees with mine (happily for me). However, my German is very poor (actually within an epsilon nbhd of zero actually) so if you know of any translation of the paper that would be awesome. Thanks again!

Comment: @Laurent Duval   Thanks! Do you know of an English translation of that Hilbert Paper?